# App crash while setting Box APi key

Tags: ios

I register by app on box.com and get API key and start using it in my xcode project,but app get crash while setting BoxAPI at line:

```
[Box setBoxAPIKey:@"insert_key_here"];.
```

The error:

> -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter

No idea how to solve this issue.

Comment: Find where you call the `initFileURLWithPath:` method. You need to see where you pass `nil` instead of a valid path.

Comment: Note - it's a bad idea to post your Box API key. Delete that line in your question. It has nothing to do with the question anyway.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your API key. It may be useful for me some day for identity theft. Saved.

Comment: There is no point closing the stable door after the horse has bolted... anyone can see the key by looking at the edits made to the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple. Follow these steps

1) Go to your target build setting

2) Click on Add Build Phase (at buttom right corner) and choose Add Run Script

3) In the Edit Text Box copy paste this script

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Copy Box database schema into bundle"
cp -fr ./Box.framework/Resources/BoxCoreDataStore.momd "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH}/BoxCoreDataStore.momd"
```

After Doing this click on build and you are done.

Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

If someone faces the same problem than here is the fix:

You need to add files in Box.framework/Resources/**BoxCoreDataStore.momd** folder to your application package.

Add "Copy Files" phase and specify Destination = Executables, Subpath = ./BoxCoreDataStore.momd then add all files from above mentioned folder.